# Put together Lookbehind and Lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I don't understand how to combine lookahead and lookbehind yet.
Does somebody have examples so I can try to understand how they work?

my regex:

```
(?<=\/|\n)[0-9 ]*
```

input:

```
544/555/716  \n
Black/Black Black  \n
100/380/236 PCS
```

expect output 1:

```
100 380 236
```

(last line, numeric only)

https://regex101.com/r/vuva70/1
I want

```
Match 1: 100
Match 2: 380
Match 3: 236
```

expect output 2:

```
544 555 716
```

Match 1: 544
Match 2: 555
Match 3: 716
(first line, split by slash, numeric only)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the lookahead part you have in mind? Is it always on the *last* line only you want to have matches, or can there be matches on a second line (also)?

Comment: `[0-9 ]*` can be zero-length (`*`) so your regex will match where the lookbehind alone matches

Comment: How would you extract `100 380 236` (no slashes) from an input that contains slahes by only regex, or do you want to extract each number? Please mention tool/lang you're using.

Comment: @bobblebubble  https://regex101.com/r/vuva70/1
I want extract each number.

Comment: `(?m)(?:\G\/|^)\K\d+(?=.*\z)` - see https://regex101.com/r/532ozw/1. Or even `\d+(?=.*\z)` - see https://regex101.com/r/532ozw/2

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew . Its was result as I want.
^^

Comment: Maybe something simple like [`(?:^.*\n)*\s*(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/krlMfz/1) in multline mode will suffice. Matches are in the first [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to combine them for this case. Get all groups of digits that do not have a newline after them:

```
(\d+)(?!.*\n)
```

EDIT: For the first line, it gets more difficult, since you have to use different techniques depending on which engine you are using. For example, in some JavaScript engines, you can use a similar technique using lookbehind; but most regex engines do not support variable-length lookbehind. You used PCRE setting in your regex101 examples; for PCRE, you can use `\G` last-match anchor like this:

```
(?:^|\G)[^\n]*?\K(\d+)
```

However, this borders on abusing regex. If possible, I would prefer to split the string into lines then split lines by slash, without use of regex.

Comment: Hi @Amanda
With old input,
But I want split by slash / , first line only.
https://regex101.com/r/vuva70/1 
I want

Match 1: 544 Match 2: 555 Match 3: 716
Please help me again,
Thanks you so much